Change Column type form varchar(32) to varchar(64) on a huge table with default charset of utfmb4
We have a situation where wants to change column from varchar(32) to varchar(64) on a huge table with default charset of utfmb4

will the change use COPY or Inplace algorithm, ie. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html

will there be any impact to running service when the algorithm change, if yes, what should be optimal update that can minimize the impact?


no changes yet since this will have impact on severel online services

Do you mean you have no dedicated test server(s)?

what have you tried ? , (the impact is likely to be minimal as allocation of addition space will be done on as required basis  -ie the length of data being stored is actually > 32. ) , test twice (or more), change once ! - have a backout/backup/recovery-plan !!!.

Extending VARCHAR column size may be performed InPlace. It does not effect the data, only metadata is altered.

As long as the number of bytes needed to store the length doesn't change, this can be done in place. Since both 32 and 64 fit in one byte, it's not a problem. If you were increasing from 32 to 512, it would need to rewrite because that requires 2 bytes for length.

@Barmar Is the stored length the number of characters or the number of bytes required for the characters? I thought the latter.  I ask because 64 characters in utfmb4 can be 256 bytes in the worst case.

@h.m.i.13 When I was writing my comment I thought it was the number of characters, but it's actually the number of bytes.
